# How do you compose two or more predicates in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to apply two (or more) predicates to a single value. For example, say I want to test if a value is a positive integer:

```
(defn posint? [n]
   (and (integer? n) (pos? n)))
```

That does it, but what if I want to compose the predicates applied? I don't want to write a function for each possible combination of predicates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Clojure 1.3 there is actually a built-in function called `every-pred` to do just this. See [here](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/every-pred).

```
(defn posint? [n]
  ((every-pred integer? pos?) n))
```

Comment: This one even handles `(posint? "a")`! I am in need of a 1.2 solution though unfortunately.

Comment: @stand: I think, that you can take this function from Clojure sources and put into your code

Answer (score 8):

If you want to compose them in an `and` relationship, use `every-pred`:

```clj
((every-pred pos? even?) 5)
;false
((every-pred pos? even?) 6)
;true
((every-pred pos? even?) -2)
;false
```

And if you want to compose them in an `or` relationship, use `some-fn`:

```clj
((some-fn pos? even?) 5)
;true
((some-fn pos? even?) 6)
;true
((some-fn pos? even?) -2)
;true
((some-fn pos? even?) -3)
;false
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to do these checks inline, the following may be what you are looking for.

```
(defn predicate-test [fns t]
    "test all predicates against value t and return true iff all predicates return true."
    (every? true? ((apply juxt fns) t)))

(predicate-test [integer? pos?] 4)
```

You could then create named versions for your most used predicate tests:

```
(def posint? (partial predicate-test [integer? pos?])

(posint? 4)
```

Comment: Ah yes, it was the `juxt` function that I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: ...though this solution throws an exception when you do a `(posint? "a")` since `pos?` throws a `CastException`. I can't think of a way to short-circuit the way `and` does.